# Not Rendering Component From Iterated Array in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `project` variable which follows this structure:

```
[
    org_id_1: {
        project_id_1: {
            title: ...
        },
        project_id_2: {
            title: ...
        }
    },
    org_id_2: {
        ...
    }
]
```

In my JSX, I want to display a `ProjectCard` component for each extracted project. I successfully loop through this structure to each individual project, but the component does not render. My code:

```
<div className='flexbox...'>
    {
        projects && Object.keys(projects).map(organisationId => {
            const projectsArray = projects[organisationId]
            projectsArray.map(project => {
                return <ProjectCard key={project.id} project={project} />
            })
        })
    }
</div>
```

I know for sure that I'm iterating through the projects because when I `console.log(project)`, or `console.log(project.title)` just before the return statement, I can see the correct values show up.

Comment: The inner map is returning the component correctly, the outer map is not returning anything

Comment: Try `return projectsArray.map(..`.

Comment: @Oblosys jinx :p

Comment: Thank you both! Adding a `return` on the nested map did the trick. If you want to write it up into an answer I'll mark it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning the outer map as the inner scope has a correct return but the outer one isn't returning anything

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to put a **return** inside the .map()

Comment: You need to be more specific.